# ImportError: cannot import name SerialPort on Twisted

Tags: python, import, twisted, pyserial

I'm having trouble with a simple twisted program and when run I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial.py", line 1, in <module>
   from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/serialport.py", line 22, in <module>
    import serial
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/serial.py", line 1, in <module>
from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort
ImportError: cannot import name SerialPort
```

I did have a bunch of fancy code, but I determined that the following line is the problem:

```
from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort
```

I'm running Twisted 13.2.0, Python 2.7 both updated as well as PySerial 2.7 installed.  So I believe everything is installed and up to date.  This error occurs on two different systems.

The following runs without issue:

```
python -c "from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort"
```

Thanks for your help.  Is it some conflict with PySerial?

Comment: Don't name your script `serial.py`.

Comment: Great idea, but it didn't help.

Comment: It probably did.  Remove the serial.pyc that Python automatically wrote out next to serial.py and is now importing.  Then make sure you have pyserial installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these lines of the traceback:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/serialport.py", line 22, in <module>
  import serial
File "/Users/me/Desktop/serial.py", line 1, in <module>
  from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort
```

Here you see that `.../twisted/internet/serialport.py` is doing this:

```
import serial
```

This is a line from Twisted.  You can guess based on this fact that the `serial` module the code wants to import is not something that you have written.

Then look at the next file in the traceback: `/Users/me/Desktop/serial.py`.  This tells you that Python found the `serial` module in your personal desktop directory.  `import serial` is now running code you wrote.  Based on the previous surmise, this is likely a bad thing.

Get rid of `serial.py` (and `serial.pyc` and `serial.pyo` if they exist) and try again.  It still may not work but the cause of the problem (and therefore the traceback) should at least be different.

Comment: That was the trick.  I was wondering why the serial.pyc file showed up.  Thank you and Wooble too.